# On premise deployment of Python Flask based REST API on LINUX Redhat server

Tags: python, linux, rest, flask, deployment

I have created a small REST API using Python and Flask and was able to deploy it on Heroku/GitHub (Cloud version).

I am not able to figure out what all I need to do to deploy the same on my on-premise LINUX Redhat server.
I was looking for a step-by-step guide for what all I need to do for this.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the documentation here:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/deploying/

> While lightweight and easy to use, Flask’s built-in server is not
>   suitable for production as it doesn’t scale well.

Now if you are not in production or if it’s a tiny project, you can deploy the files on your server using a client like WinSCP. Then you connect to your server using a ssh client like Putty and finally run:

```
python your/path/api.py
```

You can run it as below if you want it to continue executing in the background after you close your Putty window

```
python your/path/api.py &
```

Finally if you want to see if your API script is running you can use:

```
ps -efHa|grep your/path/api.py
```

It will give you the process Id which you can kill with:

```
kill <process_id>
```